# How to deploy PrestoDB on K8s using Helm Charts

Tags: docker, kubernetes, hive, kubernetes-helm, presto

I have built docker images as mentioned here - https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html

I can run this docker image as a container and query hive tables.

How I can converts this to helm chart and deploy on K8s?
Configuration given under /etc directory is static. I want to make it configurable using helm charts values.yaml so that it can be overridden as per deployment environment.

Comment: Here is a sample  repo https://github.com/dharmeshkakadia/presto-kubernetes which has all the details that you want